# How can I make my label change color when button is pressed?

Tags: swift, background-color

I need help with randomizing my labels background color when button is pressed. I would like to randomize between maybe 4 different colors than every color in the book.

```
import UIKit

class allaBarnen: UIViewController {

    let label = ["test 1", "test 2", "text 3"]

    var numberRandomHolder: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var randomTextLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        let labels = ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3", "Label4", "Hej jag hetetr iudfhsidjiui"]

        randomTextLabel.text = labels.randomElement()

        randomTextLabel.backgroundColor = randomColor()            
    }

    func randomColor() {

        let redValue = CGFloat(drand48())
        let blueValue = CGFloat(drand48())
        let greenValue = CGFloat(drand48())

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: redValue, green: greenValue, blue: blueValue, alpha: 1.0 )

    }    
 }
```

I get this error when I try to assign my func **randomColor** to my labels background color:  Cannot assign a value of type '()' to type 'UIColor?'

Comment: you are not return any thing from the function. background colour property is looking for UIColor and you assigning nothing to backgroundcolor.

Answer (score 3):

Return **UIColor**.

```
func randomColor() -> UIColor {
     let hue : CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random() % 256) / 256
     let saturation : CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random() % 128) / 256 + 0.5
     let brightness : CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random() % 128) / 256 + 0.5

     return UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: 1)
 }
```

Comment: Instead of using arc4random() you could use new `CGFloat.random(in:)`